# Reversing a string in Rust

Tags: rust

What is wrong with this:

```
fn main() {
    let word: &str = "lowks";
    assert_eq!(word.chars().rev(), "skwol");
}
```

I get an error like this:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `==` cannot be applied to type `std::iter::Rev<std::str::Chars<'_>>`
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     assert_eq!(word.chars().rev(), "skwol");
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: an implementation of `std::cmp::PartialEq` might be missing for `std::iter::Rev<std::str::Chars<'_>>`
  = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The first, and most fundamental, problem is that this isn't how you reverse a Unicode string.  You are reversing the order of the code points, where you want to reverse the order of *graphemes*.  There may be other issues with this that I'm not aware of.  Text is hard.

The second issue is pointed out by the compiler: you are trying to compare a string literal to a `char` iterator.  `chars` and `rev` don't produce new strings, they produce lazy sequences, as with iterators in general.  [The following works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=28d5452db98af404297b0e71045dabc6&version=nightly):

````
/*!
Add the following to your `Cargo.toml`:

```cargo
[dependencies]
unicode-segmentation = "0.1.2"
```
*/
extern crate unicode_segmentation;
use unicode_segmentation::UnicodeSegmentation;

fn main() {
    let word: &str = "loẅks";
    let drow: String = word
        // Split the string into an Iterator of &strs, where each element is an
        // extended grapheme cluster.
        .graphemes(true)
        // Reverse the order of the grapheme iterator.
        .rev()
        // Collect all the chars into a new owned String.
        .collect();

    assert_eq!(drow, "skẅol");

    // Print it out to be sure.
    println!("drow = `{}`", drow);
}
````

Note that `graphemes` used to be in the standard library as an unstable method, so the above will break with sufficiently old versions of Rust.  In that case, you need to use `UnicodeSegmentation::graphemes(s, true)` instead.

Comment: I think you can just `.rev().collect()`, since `String` implements `FromIterator<&str>`. Also, fwiw, I think the *actual* most fundamental problem is misunderstanding iterators, strings and types in general (understandable, many languages aren't so "pedantic"), not the somewhat finer points of unicode correctness.

Comment: @dbaupp: I'd argue a problem that is independent of the implementation language is *more* fundamental than one which is specific to a particular language.  :D  But it's nice to know `String` supports `FromIterator<&str>`.  A slight pity it doesn't pre-allocate the storage, but you can't always get what you want...

Comment: Eh, the question is about why a certain piece of code doesn't compile in a particular language, not why it is giving unexpected output (i.e. a language-independent problem with the algorithm), so the fundamental problem for the question itself is the Rust-specific type errors. It's definitely good to mention that unicode is hard, though.

Answer (score 102):

Since, as @DK. suggested, `.graphemes()` isn't available on `&str` in stable, you might as well just do what @huon suggested in the comments:

```
fn main() {
    let foo = "palimpsest";
    println!("{}", foo.chars().rev().collect::<String>());
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in DK.'s answer, **this can be wrong**. For example, it [completely fails with `"Åström"`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0a246b78ace33fc66368f8c9e81320fb)

Comment: @Shepmaster, Looks like `"Åström"` works in the above playground link with `chars()`. At least the output I see is `m̈orts̊A`. Not sure if stable was recently updated to support this.

Comment: @MilesF `Ås` vs `s̊A` / `öm` vs `m̈o`

Comment: Good point. In the playground output window, things appear to be better aligned. https://i.ibb.co/31rNjXT/chars.png

Comment: `rev` can't be called on `Chars` (anymore?)

Comment: @minseong `foo.chars().rev()` is still compiling in the playground link above. What issue where you facing?

Answer (score 0):

If you work with ASCII characters only, you can make the reversal in place *(w/o memory allocation)* with the [`reverse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.reverse) function for slices .

```
fn main() {
    let mut slice = *b"lowks";
    slice.reverse();
    assert_eq!(std::str::from_utf8(&slice).unwrap(), "skwol");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=da339b4e252761885188eb96212d118f)