# How can I reverse a string using .as_bytes()?

Tags: string, rust

I'm trying to reverse a string. I use the solution of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27996430/reversing-a-string-in-rust) and it works. But I would like to try with bytes instead of grapheme clusters as shown below:

```rust
fn reverse2(input: &str) -> String {
    input.as_bytes().iter().rev().collect()
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't run the function `collect()` after `rev()`. I don't know which method to use. How would you do it ?

Comment: `String`s in Rust are always valid UTF-8 strings, and reversing the bytes doesn't always produce valid UTF-8 strings. What you want is to reverse the `char`s (not bytes).

Answer (score 2):

As you explicitly ask about **not** using `chars()`, you have to restrict yourself to ASCII strings.

```rust
pub fn reverse2(input: &str) -> String {
    // Reversing on byte-level only works with ASCII strings.
    assert!(input.is_ascii());

    let reversed_bytes: Vec<u8> = input.as_bytes().iter().copied().rev().collect();
    let reversed_string = unsafe {
        // SAFETY: This is guaranteed to be a valid UTF8 string, because:
        // - the input string is a valid ASCII string
        // - a reversed ASCII string is still a valid ASCII string
        // - an ASCII string is a valid UTF8 string
        String::from_utf8_unchecked(reversed_bytes)
    };

    return reversed_string;
}
```

You can also use the checked version, if you don't like the `unsafe`, but it comes with a little bit of overhead:

```rust
pub fn reverse2(input: &str) -> String {
    // Reversing on byte-level only works with ASCII strings.
    assert!(input.is_ascii());

    let reversed_bytes: Vec<u8> = input.as_bytes().iter().copied().rev().collect();
    let reversed_string = String::from_utf8(reversed_bytes).unwrap();

    return reversed_string;
}
```

---

Optimization:

Checking `is_ascii()` is some overhead. It is not strictly required, however.

UTF-8 has one special property: every non-ASCII byte is valued `128` and above. So technically it is enough to just simply filter out all values equal to or above `128`:

```rust
pub fn reverse2(input: &str) -> String {
    let reversed_bytes: Vec<u8> = input
        .as_bytes()
        .iter()
        .rev()
        .map(|&val| {
            if val < 128 {
                val
            } else {
                0x1a // replacement char
            }
        })
        .collect();

    let reversed_string = unsafe {
        // SAFETY: This is guaranteed to be a valid UTF8 string, because:
        // - `reversed_bytes` is guaranteed to be an ASCII string
        // - an ASCII string is a valid UTF8 string
        String::from_utf8_unchecked(reversed_bytes)
    };

    return reversed_string;
}

fn main() {
    let s = "abcdefghij";
    println!("{:?}", s.as_bytes());

    let reversed = reverse2(s);
    println!("{}", reversed);
    println!("{:?}", reversed.as_bytes());
}
```

```
[97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 240, 159, 152, 131, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106]
jihgfedcba
[106, 105, 104, 103, 102, 26, 26, 26, 26, 101, 100, 99, 98, 97]
```

---

Additional remark:

Consider using `.bytes()` instead of `.as_bytes().iter()`.

Comment: ASCII, as I remember, contains 127 symbols, not 128. Proof: c_char’s values are -128..=127. Also isn’t cp1251 still valid?

Comment: @Miiao Yes, 127. I added `equal to or` in the text to fix that. Thanks. Everywhere else it was already correct. *"Also isn’t cp1251 still valid?"* - Valid for what? Rusts's `str` type is defined as UTF-8, so if you are talking about that, no, `str` can not be cp1251 encoded.

Comment: Why `unsafe`? Use `from_utf8().unwrap()`, unless there is a perf bottleneck.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yes, that's exactly what I wrote directly after the code example ;) The reason I used the maximum performance version first is because I can't imagine a reason why anyone wouldn't use `chars()` except for maximum performance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, firstly you ***should*** use `.bytes()` instead of `.as_bytes().iter()`. Secondly, you need to reverse characters, not bytes, cuz a `&str` may contain UTF-8, so use `.chars()` instead of `.bytes()`. Thirdly, you don’t need to collect it into a variable and return a variable, just return the result of collecting. Fourthly, you don’t need explicit `return`.

Let’s sum all the stuff i said:

```rust
pub fn reverse2(input: &str) -> String {
    input.chars()
         .rev()
         .collect()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that converts the `input` string into a byte vector ─ so the `reverse` function of `Vec` can be used:

```
pub fn reverse2(input: &str) -> String {
    let v = &mut input.to_string().into_bytes();
    v.reverse();
    std::str::from_utf8(v).unwrap().to_string()
}
```

The `input` string may only contain ASCII characters.

[Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=e230f25631a2b360d9d1c325ecaad4b5)